# Not getting the error in Video Player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, video-player

I am using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package provided by flutter team to implement a video player in my flutter project. Everything is working fine when internet is connected. But the problem with me is I could not get the error while turning off my internet and also when I am providing wrong video url to the video player controller. Below is my code:-

```
videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(alertClipList[0]);
          videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
            print('here');
            if(videoPlayerController.value.isBuffering){
              print('buffering');
            }else if(videoPlayerController.value.hasError){
              print('error');
            }else if(videoPlayerController.value.position == videoPlayerController.value.duration){
              print('completed');
            }
          });
          var temp = await videoPlayerController.initialize().then((value){
            print('started');
            if(videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying){
              print('already playing');
              return;
            }
            videoPlayerController.play();
          }, onError: (error){
            print(error);
            print('error is here');
          });
```

And here is the simple UI code:

```
  Widget JVideoPlayer() {
    return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        child: VideoPlayer(alertClipController.videoPlayerController));
  }
```

Also I using the below implementation of exoplayer

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.16.1'
```

Comment: What about checking internet connection?, can that solve your problem? You can use connectivity package for it.

Comment: I could use it but what if wrong url is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing this line from my app level build.gradle file - implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.16.1'. I think there is no problem with the video player package, the problem is with the exoplayer.